# Not woking UIView ishidden after change UILabel text value in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to change uilabel value and show uiview that has hide like a popup windows.

When I touch a button, that code print "setPopupView 0".
but doesn't show settingView.
and I touch a button again.
print "setPopupView 0" and show settingView.

so When "settingLabelValueUnit text" has changed not show settingView,
but when "settingLabelValueUnit text" has not changed show settingView.
(It means "settingLabelValue text" is same as input value)

I don't know why.

Anyone can help me?
Thank you

here is my swift code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var workoutScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var settingLabelValueUnit: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imgSettingBGcal: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgSettingBGdis: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imgSettingBGcal.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(calSettingClick)))
        self.imgSettingBGdis.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(disSettingClick)))
    }

    func calSettingClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        setPopupView(0)
    }

    func disSettingClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        setPopupView(1)
    }

    func showPopup (_ settype:Int) {
        switch settype {
        case 0:
            print("setPopupView 0")
            self.settingLabelValueUnit.text = "Set1"
            self.workoutScrollView.isHidden = true
            self.settingView.isHidden = false

        case 1:
            print("setPopupView 0")
            self.settingLabelValueUnit.text = "Set2"
            self.workoutScrollView.isHidden = true
            self.settingView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to share the code showing how you are trying to display the popup. As in, is it already in the view hierarchy and how its set up.

Comment: I add another codes.

Comment: when you said "When I touch a button, that code print "setPopupView 0". but doesn't show settingView. and I touch a button again. print "setPopupView 0" and show settingView" what buttons were you talking about? What are the methods attached to those buttons. And what do `calSettingClick` and `disSettingClick` methods mean?

Comment: It mean that touch `UIImageView` by `UITapGestureRecognizer`. so It call `calSettingClick` or `disSettingClick`